# Why am I not able to edit someone's post?

Tags: discussion

I tried to edit one person post but I couldn't edit. What's the reason behind it?
When will I be able to edit someone post again? From where to know when I
 can edit someone posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most your edits have been rejected, as they are too minor and only changed one word or tag. While sometimes this is important - most times *change more than one thing* (not just 2 tags, find some spelling/capitals in there as well) until you have the privilege to edit without suggestions.

Other times you have introduced information - that should be presented to the user as a comment such as https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/182255 or https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/181755

Based on - https://askubuntu.com/help/editing you will need to wait 7 days.

> Additionally, any user who submits many rejected edits will be banned
>   from suggesting further edits for 7 days.